# Avoid storing permutations of all possible product configurations

Tags: sql, database-design

I'll simplify my problem using a shirt analogy. I have the following tables:

- shirt sizes (e.g. small, medium, large...)
- shirt colors (e.g. red, green, blue...)
- shirt styles (e.g. short sleeve, long sleeve, collared...)

Now, I'd like to create prices for my inventory. Not all shirts are available in every configuration, but some are. For example:

- All shirt styles and sizes are available in green. These are $1.
- Only large, collared shirts are available in blue. These are $2.
- Short sleeve red shirts in all sizes are $3, but long sleeve and collared red shirts are $4.

I could create another table with all available combinations of the three tables and store the prices. This seems inefficient and prone to error. How else can I store these relationships?

Comment: You can either explicitly list the combinations or you can build some "smart" multilevel business rules so that you can derive them... but the "smart" business rule approach is the one that is actually prone to failure because it's complex and you have to account for every edge case.

Comment: For example, the $2 shirts - are they $2 because they are blue or because they are large or because they are collared or a combination of two or three of these things?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with a *Prices* table that has foreign keys to those shirt lookup tables.

Comment: I third this. Go for a pricing table. Other thing to consider is that if your rules change, it's much harder to keep track of the set of rules that were active at any one time than to keep a history of price for each item. If you want you can also create a stored proc that encapsulates your pricing rules, but then writes the result of those rules into your pricing table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Background

Its important to know the terminology and the lexicon when you are researching how to accomplish something.  What you are looking to do here is basically design a *product configurator* or *configure price quote* (CPQ) system.  These systems exists as proprietary and open source customizable off the shelf solutions. As a software architect for a mid market B2B company I am quite familiar with software that implements cpq from scratch and also software that integrates with COTs solutions. If this is anything but an academic exercise I would highly suggest you look at the myriad of free OSS CPQ tools. However since this is stack overflow I will address your question on a more technical level.

## Four abstract layers

There are essentially four abstract layers to designing a product configuration system (which we will call a product configuration model).

- Components and subcomponents
- Attributes shared between those components
- Tables / Relational Constraints connecting the components and sub components with their shared attributes
- Expressions and expression constraints (which are non reusable statements that are conceptually the bottom layer)

## Components

Let's take something simple like skateboards as a use case here.  You may have a components table similar to the following

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|     id              |       Name       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       1             |       Decks      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       2             |       Wheels     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       3             |       Trucks     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

### Sub Components

You may then have a sub components table similar to the following

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|     id              |       Name       |   component_id   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       1             |       Bearings   |        2         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       2             |       Bushing    |        3         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       3             |       Grip Tape  |        1         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       4             |    Nuts / Bolts  |        1         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

As you can you in this simple example you have one to one and one to many relationship between components and sub components.  *It is important that you do not confuse this with attributes, which we have not addressed yet*.

## Attributes

Your next layer of abstraction is attributes.  Generally, all your attributes are associated with table constraints to components and sub components, *and they are not limited to whether that particular combination exists or not).

For a simplied example you might have a table *attributes* with the following rows

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|     id              |       Category   |      Value       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       1             |       Size       |        7.5       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       2             |       Size       |        7.75      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       3             |       Size       |        6.25      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       4             |      Brand       |    Toy Machine   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       5             |      Brand       |    Bird House    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       5             |      Brand       |      Nike        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       5             |      Model       |     Nyjah Pro    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       5             |      Model       |  Vice Monster    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       6             |    ABEC Rating   |     class 6      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       7             |    ABEC Rating   |     class 3      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

As you can see this table is not constrained in the same way your product major and product minor is (however, this is an over simplification and you'd obviously be using business keys in place of attribute labels like *ABEC Rating*, etc.  It lists all attributes.

## Expressions

Finally, you would have a table for expressions.  These expressions would be stored as rows in the table.  They may be relational with other expressions (recursive keys), but should not be relational with your tables. Rather, they should use a mixture of boolean logic, predefined functions, and the surrogate keys from your previous tables to specify the actual configurations available.  These are generally NOT reusable (but can be combined with recursive keys for a bit more re-usability).

There are a variety of expression languages out there, some proprietary some open.  I manage a custom built product configuration model that uses DMN (from the people who brought you BPMN) to express my statements.

Additionally, I have seem people use XML, XSLT, and XPath in place of the relational model listed above. An expression row might look something like the following

```
(/component/id@1  & (/attribute/@id == 6 | /attribute/@id == 7))
```

## In Conclusion

Like any software system, abstraction is key.  I have seen almost all CPQ and product configuration models boil down into these 4 abstractions (with hundreds of other abstractions in between).  Unless this is an academic exercise I highly suggest you find a COTs solution.  Knowing your products enough to abstract between major, minor, and attributes is key but the bread and butter (and unfortunately the "least clean" part is definitely the expression language you store in your tables).

Comment: Can you give a couple examples of the "myriad of free OSS CPQ tools"?

Answer (score 1):

Storing all the combinations isn't such a bad idea.  But, you could also use wildcards.  Your conditions would look like:

```
style                   size     color     price
NULL                    NULL     green     $1
collared                large    blue      $2
short sleeve            NULL     red       $3
long sleeve, collared   NULL     red       $4
```

If you have only a handful of different prices, then this is probably okay.  However, querying such a table would be less efficient than expanding it out for every combination.

Comment: I’ve used this idea many times. As you say If the rules are simple it’s works well. Trouble is once you get a conflicting entry you either have to add scoring or add every possible sub value in.